# Converting View's touch location to WebView's HTML screen location

Tags: javascript, android, drag-and-drop

I have a `WebView` that is displaying a local HTML page within the assets folder. The `WebView` is part of larger layout in an `Activity`. I'm trying to allow users to drag text from an `EditText` widget to an Input Element within the `WebView`. Everything works good except for converting the screen coordinates received by the drag listener to the screen coordinates used by `document.elementFromPoint`.  They don't match up. It'll keep dropping text into input boxes which are further down then the users finger.  Any help would be appreciated. Warning: my javascript knowledge is pretty pathetic.

Basic flow:

1. WebView's onDrag event catches the ACTION_DROP event.
2. The event's x, y location is passed to a Javascript function
3. The Javascript function finds element based on points and updates the value

In my Activity:

```java
private class OnWebViewDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                String dropText = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                mJavaScript._dropText(mWebView, dropText, event.getX(), event.getY());
                return true;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Javascript wrapper:

```java
public void _dropText(WebView wv, String text, float x, float y) {
    wv.loadUrl("javascript:dropText('" + text + "', " + x + ", " + y + ")");
}
```

Javascript function:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropText(text, x, y) {
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    if (elem.tagName == "INPUT") {
        elem.value = text;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out. Was making the conversion more complicated then what it needed to be.  Both Android's WebView and the WebPage have their own coordinate system based on the size of their visible view port. Yes both report different sized view ports.  Even though both view ports can be scrolled, there's no need to include those scrolled changes. The simple formula:

DE = DragEvent
WV = WebView

x = DE.getX() * (window.innerWidth / WV.getWidth()); 
y = DE.getY() * (window.innerHeight / WV.getHeight());

How my code looks now:

**In Activity:**

```java
private class OnWebViewDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                String dropText = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                mJavaScript._dropText(mWebView, dropText, event.getX(), event.getY());
                return true;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Javascript wrapper:**

```java
public void _dropText(WebView wv, String text, float x, float y) {
    wv.loadUrl("javascript:dropText('" + text + "', " + x + ", " + y + ", " + wv.getHeight()
            + ", " + wv.getWidth() + ")");
}
```

**Javascript function:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropText(text, x, y, height, width) {
    x *= (window.innerWidth / width);
    y *= (window.innerHeight / height);

    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    if (elem.tagName == "INPUT") {
        elem.value = text;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Jay, thanks for this great solution. I spend few hours banging my head trying to figure out best way to translate coordinates :) Btw, did you have some issue while you drag your object? For example I keep getting this "Drag is in progress but there is no drag window handle" and because of that my on touch move event stop triggering. Here's my code for that https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8161cae250a9f0c9002a

Comment: It sounds vaguely familiar but can't totally recall.  It's been 3 years and I no longer have access to this code.

Comment: Worked fine for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: These days it's equivalent to `cssX = viewX / window.devicePixelRatio; cssY = viewY / window.devicePixelRatio`. This assumes the HTML viewport fills all the webview.